# Remove border of one cell in Bootstrap Table

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'd like to remove the border of just one cell in a bootstrap table. I've tried putting an id on that particular cell and in my css putting:

```
#borderless-cell { border: 0; }
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Issue is that, you would also need to remove the border around the surrounding cells for it to take effect

Comment: you can debug what styles are applying on the first cell by clicking on the 'INSPECT ELEMENT' on chrome browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#borderless-cell { border: 1px solid Transparent!important; }
```

Make border transparent to that particular cell

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap 4 has utility classes built in that may help:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/

Example from Documentation:

```
<span class="border-0"></span>
```

You may also review the CSS used to make border-0 work for a hint to answer your question in pure CSS.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```
#borderless-cell { border: none!important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use This One.

Change this: `<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">`

To this: `<table class="table table-hover">`

And then add this css:

```
.table {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

However, if you want to do it the way you're doing it, the css is:

```
.table-bordered > thead > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-bordered > thead > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right-width:0px;
  border-left-width:0px;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/IbebIpob/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

hide that with a transparent border

```
#borderless-cell { border: 10px solid transparent; }
```